# YouTube/Flash causes Windows 7 x64 to lockup in all browsers

Tags: windows-7, browser, crash, adobe-flash

**Symptoms:**

- **While doing this:** viewing some flash videos (almost always on YouTube and Vimeo, some other sites play fine). This only occurs in Flash video players, never on full flash websites and other heavy flash apps.
- **This happens:** I will see the video begin to load, and then the computer immediately locks up.
- Sometimes, I will not be able to do anything with the mouse or keyboard - and I will **have to hold the power button**, and **other times I have been able to minimize the browser, however even with Task Manager I am unable to kill the process, which displays at 50% CPU usage.** I am able to close and save other applications - though I am not able to shut down or restart through Windows, and I am forced to hold in the power button.

  - On times where I have had to hold the power button in, this has caused me to lose data previously, even corrupting files open in Notepad++ (not just stuff unsaved, the entire file is killed - luckily I had verbose backups so most was recovered); and also more than once I have rebooted and then started Chrome to be greeted with the message that my profile is corrupt, and I lose all my applications (however, strangely enough their settings still persist when they are reinstalled. Since then I have enabled extension sync to prevent this from being too damaging).

**System:**

- Windows 7 x64
- 4GB ram (checked with memtest)

**I have tried:**

- Chkdsk-ing my main and data drives
- Using Firefox 3.5, 3.6, Chrome 5, Chrome 6, Safari 5
- Upgrading Flash
- Uninstalling and reinstalling Flash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also try flash squared (flash for 64 bit beta)
or if you would like to watch stuff without flash, enable HTML5 preview on youtube by going to youtube.com/html5

Answer (score -1):

Get rid of anything Shockwave (check add ins section of Firefox as well), and update your video card drivers.